# Store/Map Data of Custom View inside UITextView

Tags: ios, swift, database, uitextview, html-parsing

I am trying to achieve an editable `textView` with the ability to embed a 'Custom `View`' as shown:

[image]

This view encompasses 2 textfields (it is showing a word definition). The `view` dynamically changes dependant on what definition is selected. I have currently been able to add it to the textView as an `NSAttachment` as an image (since I can't attach a custom `view` to a `textView`) but if I go about it this way I have no way of accessing what the text is inside the custom view if I need to update the view.

Can anyone give me a solution where I would be able to store the info that is in the custom view somehow? I want to make sure in future I would be able to actually access the data in case the view design changes and I wanted to update it. Do I need to change to a `WebView` and somehow create a custom parse in HTML that looks for  definition info  and then formats it?

**EDIT:** Code used to create NSAttachment. The returnView() function returns a view object as shown in red in the photo above. The rest of the viewController is just a textView which saves the NSAttributedString to a Core Data Object.

```
func viewToNSAttachment() {

    let view = returnView()
    view.layoutIfNeeded()

    // Render Image
    let renderer = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size: view.frame.size)
    let image = renderer.image {
        view.layer.render(in: $0.cgContext)
    }

    // Create Attachment
    let attachment = NSTextAttachment()
    attachment.image = image
    attachment.bounds = CGRect(origin: .zero, size: image.size)

    // Current Attributed String
    let atStr = NSMutableAttributedString(attributedString: textView.attributedText)

    // Insert Attachment
    let attachmentAtStr = NSAttributedString(attachment: attachment)
    if let selectedRange = textView.selectedTextRange {
        let cursorIndex = textView.offset(from: textView.beginningOfDocument, to: selectedRange.start)
        atStr.insert(attachmentAtStr, at: cursorIndex)
        atStr.addAttributes(self.textView.typingAttributes, range: NSRange(location: cursorIndex, length: 1))
    } else {
        atStr.append(attachmentAtStr)
    }
    textView.attributedText = atStr
}
```

Comment: If you don't get much help after few hours, would you consider sharing a sample project of yours for this particular question?

Comment: Hi @Glenn I have added the code I used to create the custom view as an NSAttachment  and add to the textView above. I'd appreciate any help you can give me! Thanks heaps :)

Comment: Is that enough info @Glenn Any thoughts?

Comment: I think there's no way to get your attachment as `UIView`, cause it has been rendered as `UIImageView`. You might want to try this: https://github.com/rickytan/RTViewAttachment or any similar lib.

Comment: Yep, I can't have a UIView. What I am wanting to know is how I could map the data that is in the view. That way I would just use the data to 'redraw the image' if necessary.